# Using hibernate and get "could not get a field value by reflection" error

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate to mapping and class but i getting and error. I my mapping is one student has many school subjects. I make the database first i'm using postgres. Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE aluno
(
  idAluno serial,
  datanascimento date,
  matricula character varying(255),
  nome character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT pkAluno PRIMARY KEY (idAluno)
);

CREATE TABLE materiaaluno
(
  idCurso serial,
  nome character varying(255),
  idAluno integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pkMateriAluno PRIMARY KEY (idcurso),
  CONSTRAINT fkAluno FOREIGN KEY(idAluno) REFERENCES aluno(idAluno)
);
```

> Warning:   #{alunoBean.salvar()}: java.lang.Exception: could not get a field value by reflection getter of modelo.Materia.idcurso
>   javax.faces.FacesException: #{alunoBean.salvar()}: java.lang.Exception: could not get a field value by reflection getter of modelo.Materia.idcurso

Aluno class

```
package modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "aluno")
public class Aluno implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idaluno")
private Integer idaluno;

@Column(name = "nome")
private String nome;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "datanascimento")
private Date datanascimento;

@Column(name = "matricula")
private String matricula;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "aluno", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Materia> materias;

// contructors, getters and setters

}
```

Materia class

```
package modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "materiaaluno")
public class Materia implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idcurso")
private Integer idcurso;

@Column(name = "nome")
private String nome;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idaluno")
private Aluno aluno;

// constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is a hibernate exception and not a JSF? `javax.faces.FacesException`

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot/miswrote the setters and getters in the entity `Materia`.
Hibernate tries to access the fields by reflection when it can't do otherwise.

Check the field `idcurso`

Comment: My friend gave me the same suggestion, i tried tried but doesn't work, i checked each getter and setter, after I generate all automatically but continuing give the same erro. I really appreciate any help you can provide. Link pastebin [link](https://pastebin.com/mqE1nGy5)